# Typescript compiling when property doesn't exist - using dot vs using square brackets

Tags: typescript, tsc

Let's say I have the following class and code -

```
export class MyClass{
   a: number;
}
const o = new MyClass();
o.b = 5; // compile error. Property 'b' does not exist on type MyClass.
o['b'] = 5; // does compile.
```

What the difference between using dot and using square brackets. It's basically the same, isn't it?

Comment: In Typescript, when using bracket notation (eg. `o['b'] = 5;`), type checking is ignored.

Comment: That's my question - why. Where did the type-safety of TypeScript disappear?

Comment: This has nothing to do with type safety: Even in strong statically typed languages like c# where a `Dictionary<string, object>` would compile if a given key wasn't present in the `Dictionary` but would fail at run-time. You have the option in TS to turn this off

Answer (score 4):

When you use brackets like `o['b']`, you are treating the `o` object as an `any` object which means Typescript is not going to apply any type checks to it.

You can tell it to give you warnings by adding in your `tsconfig.json` file the attribute `noImplicitAny: true`.  This will cause `o['b']` to give an `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'MyClass' has no index signature.` error.  Then to get around it you'd have to explicitly state that `o` is to be treated as an any like so: `(o as any)['b']`.

One exception to this is if you define an attribute in `MyClass` that exists.  For example:

```
export class MyClass{
   a: number;
   "Weirdly-Named-Attribute": number;
}
const o = new MyClass();
o["a"] = 4; // compiles
o["Weirdly-Named-Attribute"] = 5; // compiles
o["b"] = 6; // Gives `Element implicitly has an 'any' type` error if `noImplicityAny` is enabled in tsconfig.
```

Answer (score 1):

`o.b` is understood by the compiler as : " I want to initialize this attribute (`b` in our case) of the class `MyClass` ". That's why there is a compile error.
However the `o['b']` creates a new attribute `b` in the instance `o` of type `MyClass` so this will compile.

So basically the difference between using dot and using square brackets is that dot will try to access the wanted property of the instance and the square brackets will, if the property exist in the class, assign the value to the property. If not, it will create the attribute and assign the value.